# Running command line program using Django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to execute a command line programa through Django using the subprocess.check_output(). I have tried to do it first with simple commands like:

subprocess.check_output('ls', '-l')

And its working ok, but now I'm trying to do it with a command line program, which I have already put in the root folder of my project (so if I execute a 'ls -l' it appears there) but Django is throwing me an 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

The programs needs to be in somewhere particularly? This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
        output = subprocess.check_output(['kmersFreq', 'sequence.fasta', '2', '0'])
        print output
```

Answer (score 0):

add shell = True argument in your subprocess call